# Why does this print out so many responses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So here is my code.. I'm currently working on a Udacity course and made up this code for one of their quizzes. It gives me the answer I am looking for.. but perhaps too many iterations seem to be occurring and I'm not exactly sure why. If anyone can help me reduce it to one iteration or response being printed that would be great.

```
numList = [422, 136, 524, 85, 96, 719, 85, 92, 10, 17, 312, 542, 87, 23, 
   86, 191, 116, 35, 173, 45, 149, 59, 84, 69, 113, 166]
   oddNumList = []
   total = 0

for num in numList:
    if num % 2 != 0:
        oddNumList.append(num)
        if len(oddNumList) < 5:
            print("There are more than 5 odd numbers in this list")
        else:
            for ele in range(0, len(oddNumList)):
                total = total + oddNumList[ele]
                print("Sum of all odd numbers is {}!".format(total))
```

Comment: "Perhaps" too many iterations?

Comment: well your looped if else is: either print once or print once for every element in a growing list

Comment: Unindent all the code starting at `if len(oddNumList)` so it doesn't reside within the for loop.

Comment: `if len(oddNumList)<5: print("There are more than 5 odd numbers in this list")` how come? shoudn't it be `>`?

Comment: FYI if you don't care how many odd numbers there are in the list, you can sum the odd numbers using: `sum([a for a in numList if a%2!=0])`

Comment: What is the objective here? It appears that you want the sum of all odd numbers in the list. Why not just add them as you go along. Or, even simpler, *print(sum([x for x in numList if x % 2 != 0]))*

Answer (score 0):

You do many thinks more than one. If i would have to guess i would try:

```py
numList = [422, 136, 524, 85, 96, 719, 85, 92, 10, 17, 312, 542, 87, 23, 
   86, 191, 116, 35, 173, 45, 149, 59, 84, 69, 113, 166]
   oddNumList = []
   total = 0

for num in numList:
    if num % 2 != 0:
        oddNumList.append(num)
# output part
if len(oddNumList) < 5:
    print("There are more than 5 odd numbers in this list")
else:
    for ele in range(0, len(oddNumList)):
        total = total + oddNumList[ele]
    print("Sum of all odd numbers is {}!".format(total))
```

otherwise the output function would be called after every check.

Also try to calculate the total with the sum function: `sum(oddNumList)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate over the list twice, it's sufficient to do both filtering of odd numbers and computation of their sum in one run. Also, I moved printing of the information out of the loop so it prints only when the computation is done.

```py
numList = [422, 136, 524, 85, 96, 719, 85, 92, 10, 17, 312, 542, 87, 23, 
   86, 191, 116, 35, 173, 45, 149, 59, 84, 69, 113, 166]
oddNumList = []
total = 0

for num in numList:
    if num % 2 != 0:
        oddNumList.append(num)
        # Add odd number to total
        total = total + num

# Prints the information about odd numbers list length        
if len(oddNumList) < 5:
    print("There are more than 5 odd numbers in this list")
# Prints the sum of all odd numbers
print("Sum of all odd numbers is {}!".format(total))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
oddNumList = [x for x in numList if x%2!=0]
print("There are more than 5 odd numbers in this list") if len(oddNumList)>5 else print("less then 5")
for n in oddNumList:
    total = total+n
print("Sum of all odd numbers is {}!".format(total))
```

Comment: This answer was flagged for review as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality) and could benefit from an explanation. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not good answers** and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted  because they are **not useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / better than existing answers (if there are any). [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29834852)